# Query Store Settings

Tags: sql-server, query-store

I'm interested in the overall CPU utilization for a database in a time span.  I see how to get that, but I'm concerned about the query store retention settings.

I don't need detailed info about each query execution, but because of the FK from sys.query_store_runtime_stats to sys.query_store_plan, it appears that the overall resource consumption isn't aggregated in total, but only per-plan.  My concern is that if plans are dropped because of a Query Store Capture Mode of Auto and a Size-Based Cleanup Mode of Auto, then I think that means that the execution times for dropped queries won't be included in the totals for an interval.

The docs say *"Infrequent queries and queries with insignificant compile and execution duration are ignored"*, and what worries me there is the word "and".  Will it drop a 1-time query that uses tons of CPU?  Since *"Thresholds for execution count, compile and runtime duration are internally determined."*, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, no it will not drop that 1 time cpu heavy query

It may have an insignificant compile time, but the execution is not insignificant

But if you are interested in a very accurate measurement of total cpu utilization that includes every request, you should not use a Query Store Capture Mode of 'Auto', then it should be 'All'